# yii2 error in ajax request in controller redirect function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have this request in js

```
requestSend: function(e)
{
    let data = {
        request_id: e.target.dataset.request_id
    };
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/posts/save-changes',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: data,
        success: function()
        {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function()
        {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
},
```

In php controller everything looks like this

```
public function actionSaveChanges()
    {
        $post = \Yii::$app->request->post();
        $this->Posts->updateFields($post['request_id'],$post);

        return \Yii::$app->controller->redirect('/posts');
    }
```

And when the request is executed, `error` comes to my console. In the JSE itself, I checked all the data, everything comes up correctly there, it turns out that the error is on the php side. I used var_dump before the return line, and in the request I always got `success`. It turns out that the problem is with the return, specifically with the redirect. But what could be wrong here and how can it be done differently?

Comment: you can't do a redirect in the PHP ajax function, you must return the wanted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to redirect the page.
In the controller, return a response like this:

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

public function actionSaveChanges()
{
    $post = \Yii::$app->request->post();
    $this->Posts->updateFields($post['request_id'], $post);
    return $this->asJson([
        'url' => Url::to('/posts')
    ]);
}
```

In js, change your code like this:

```
requestSend: function(e){
let data = {
    request_id: e.target.dataset.request_id
};
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/posts/save-changes',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: data,
    success: function(result)
    {
    window.location.href = result.url
    },
    error: function()
    {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
},
```